# How to Check if Click in Selenium Webdriver Changed Page in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've been reading that click() using Selenium's webdrivers is asynchronous, so I've been trying to have the webdriver wait for the click to go through before doing anything else. I am using PhantomJS as my browser.

I have the WebDriverWait objects to wait for an element on the page to change (that's how I'm telling if the page has loaded/changed once I've clicked on something). My issue is that I keep getting TimeoutExceptions from the WebDriverWait.

Is there something that I could do to wait for the page to load after I click something? I don't want to have to use `time.sleep(1)` because there seems to be a variable loading time, and I don't want it to sleep for too long. This is why I want to explicitly wait for the page to load.

Here is my code for the webdriver and corresponding waiting:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.common.exceptions as exceptions

class Webdriver():

    def __init__(self, wait_time=10):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1200,800)
        self.wait = wait_time

    def click(self, element_xpath, wait_xpath, sleep_time=0):
        wait = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.wait)
        old_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(wait_xpath)
        old_text = old_element.text
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
        wait.until(lambda driver: element_changed(driver, wait_xpath, old_text,20))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

def element_changed(driver, element_xpath, old_element_text, timeout_seconds=10):
    pause_interval = 1
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < timeout_seconds:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
            if element.text != old_element_text:
                return True
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
            return True
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        time.sleep(pause_interval)
    return False
```

Here is the code that runs:

```
driver = Webdriver()
url = 'http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx?tab=parameters'
wait_xpath = '//*[@id="device-columns"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/a'
driver.load(url, wait_xpath)
soup = driver.get_soup()

pages = soup('ul', class_='pagination')[0]('a')
num_pages = len(pages)
products = set()
for i in range(num_pages):
    element_xpath = '//*[@id="top-nav"]/div/ul/li[%d]/a' % (2 + i)
    driver.click(element_xpath, wait_xpath)
    soup = driver.get_soup()
    for tag in soup('td', class_='first-cell'):
        product = tag.find('div', class_='anchor')
        if not product:
            continue
        else:
            if product.find('a'):
                products.add(product.find('a')['href'])
```

**UPDATE**

Part of my problem is that I was reloading the first page and expecting it to change. But even then, moving the clicking line and soup line down after the for-loop, there would be times it would take too long to change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the WebDriverWait, I just made a function to wait until it was loaded. It seems to work now, but I can't help but feel it's unstable and doesn't always work.

```
def click(self, element_xpath, wait_xpath=None, sleep_time=0):
    if wait_xpath:
        old_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(wait_xpath)
        old_text = old_element.text
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
    if wait_xpath:
        if not element_changed(self.driver, wait_xpath, old_text):
            log.warn('click did not change element at %s', wait_xpath)
            return False
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    return True

def element_changed(driver, element_xpath, old_element_text, timeout_seconds=10):
    pause_interval = 1
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < timeout_seconds:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
            if element.text != old_element_text:
                return True
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
            return True
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        time.sleep(pause_interval)
    return False
```

The run code is this:

```
driver = Webdriver()
url = 'http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx?tab=parameters'
wait_xpath = '//*[@id="device-columns"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/a'
driver.load(url, wait_xpath)
soup = driver.get_soup()

pages = soup('ul', class_='pagination')[0]('a')
num_pages = len(pages)
products = set()
for i in range(num_pages):
    element_xpath = '//*[@id="top-nav"]/div/ul/li[%d]/a' % (2 + i)
    if i == 0:
        driver.click(element_xpath, None, 1)
    else:
        driver.click(element_xpath, wait_xpath, 1)
    soup = driver.get_soup()
    for tag in soup('td', class_='first-cell'):
        product = tag.find('div', class_='anchor')
        if not product:
            continue
        else:
            if product.find('a'):
                products.add(product.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: As a sidenote, I found your try/except StaleElementReferenceException useful.